# Why does type(mock.MagicMock()) == mock.MagicMock returns False?

Tags: python-3.x, typechecking

In Python3.4:

```
>>> import mock.MagicMock
>>> type(mock.MagicMock()) == mock.MagicMock
False # Huh, why is that?
>>> isinstance(mock.MagicMock(), mock.MagicMock)
True
```

When I simplify this to class `A` and `B` I `type(B()) == B` returns `True`:

```
>>> class A: pass
>>> class B: pass
>>> class C(A, B): pass
>>> type(B()) == B    
True # Of course I would say.
```

Why returns `type(mock.MagicMock()) == mock.MagicMock` `False`? I know about the [difference between `isinstance()` and `type()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) in Python. `type()` doesn't 'understand' subclassing where `isinstance` does. But I don't see how that is that difference is involved here.

[source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/408bbdaef8d4/Lib/unittest/mock.py#l1831) of `mock.MagicMock`.

Comment: Note that `type(B()) == B` is `False` in Python 2.7.

Comment: Maybe a different question, why?

Comment: @Simeon Visser and @OrangeTux  Before Python 3, `class C(): pass` resulted in an old-style class.  Every old-style class is an instance of class 'classob' (rather than of class 'type') and *every* instance of any old-style class is an instance of class 'instance', not the class used to create it.  Old-style classes were deleted in 3.0, so that `class C(): pass` is the same as `class C(object): pass` was in 2.2+ and still is in 3.x, an instance of `type`.

Comment: @OrangeTux  You must have omitted something, such as `import unittest.mock as mock`, since mock is a module within the unittest package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More experiments suggest the answer.

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock as mm
>>> mm1 = mm()
>>> mm2 = mm()
>>> type(mm1)
<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
>>> type(mm2)
<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
>>> type(mm1) == type(mm2)
False
>>> id(type(mm1))
53511896
>>> id(type(mm2))
53510984
>>> type(mm1) is mm1.__class__
True
>>> mm
<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
>>> id(mm)
53502776
```

Conclusion: each instance of MagicMock has a 'class' that looks like MagicMock, but is not.  What is the **new** that creates such instances?  MagicMock subclasses Mock, which subclasses NonCallableMock, which has this **new** method.

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
    # every instance has its own class
    # so we can create magic methods on the
    # class without stomping on other mocks
    new = type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {'__doc__': cls.__doc__})
    instance = object.__new__(new)
    return instance
```

The `new = ...` statement creates a subclass of the `cls` argument with the same name and docstring.  The next line creates a single instance of this subclass.  So Mocks follow a revised equality instead of `type(mm()) is mm`.

```
>>> mm.__bases__
(<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMixin'>, <class 'unittest.mock.Mock'>)
>>> type(mm1).__bases__
(<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>,)
>>> type(mm1).__bases__[0] is mm
True
```